# eclipse java file shows question mark, cause Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, eclipse

I am a newbie. [image]I download a project from github. i can run this project rightly. But when i write a new java file, the new java file shows question mark(?) in Eclipse. And it shows

```
"Error: Could not find or load main class com.talis.hbase.rdf.examples.Test"
```

How can i solve this error? By the way, in command line, run this java file, no error.

Comment: Question mark means its an unstaged file by git. Nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Mordechai, but when i run this java file, i show "Error: Could not find or load main class com.talis.hbase.rdf.examples.Test"

Comment: Unless you’ve told maven you have non-standard directories it’s only going to look in standard directories.

Comment: @Dave Newton， how can i tell maven i have non-standard directory?

Comment: Don’t recall, and it’s rarely worth it. Just put it where it belongs-you already have packaging to differentiate types of code.

Comment: @Dave Newton, what's the meaning of "recall"?  Does it refer to "create a new java file"?

Comment: No, it means I don't remember.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remove .metadata file in eclipse workplace. And reimport the project. It may be risky. But it's Ok for me.

Answer (score 0):

The question mark indicates that file is not yet committed to the GIT repository.

Comment: But it doesn't affect compile and run.